# How to plot multiple 3D grids of coordinates together in Python (to visualize multiple cubes essentially)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have one large 4x4x4x3 shape array of coordinate points (so a 4x4x4 grid where each grid point is an x, y, z coordinate point), and I've split this up into multiple smaller blocks, say 8x2x2x2x3 (so 8 smaller 2x2x2 blocks). However, I'm unsure of whether the way I've split the larger grid into smaller blocks has preserved the ordering of the coordinates such that the smaller blocks are themselves smaller cubes. I'm trying to verify this by plotting the large meshgrid of points as well as all of the smaller grids of points together (while being able to distinguish between them), how could I go about doing this?

Right now I'm trying to plot just my simple large grid of points with the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.scatter3D(rotated_grids_4_2_3d[:, 0], rotated_grids_4_2_3d[:, 1], rotated_grids_4_2_3d[:, 2])
plt.show()
```

Where, for example, `rotated_grids_4_2_3d[:, 0]` is just a 2D array of the x coordinate values. However, this method seems to be skipping points, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It is easier to help if you could provide the original `4x4x4x3 array` and `rotated_grids_4_2_3d`.

Comment: @scleronomic Can do! How would you prefer it? Some sort of saved .npy file, or the code I used for generating it (this might be more complicated since I'm using PyTorch tensors that I converted over to Numpy for the sake of trying to visualize them)?

Comment: I thought you could just post them. `(4, 4, 4, 3)` should be doable.

Comment: Did you made progress? Is this question still relevant?

Comment: Hey, thanks for following up! I ended up just manually inspecting smaller versions of the arrays to try to match.